# How to manage both dialog reuse and conversation lifetime?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I use @RemusRusanu's blog examples for Service Broker to address some ETL-like issue. It's working well. I understood that not setting LIFETIME property in dialog conversation may end in DB growing unexpectedly until Int32.Max seconds wait time is reached, that releases DB objects related to stale conversations. Setting low value for LIFETIME property shall help resources being released.

But how can I handle RR's dialog reuse technique, with the table pattern (e.g storing conversation GUID for each DB dialoging) and, in the same time, set some LIFETIME property? As far as I am not aware of when it times out, expected drawback will be blindly reusing an ended conversation next time I will query the table to get dialog ID for the same DB, which will obviously raise some exception.

Is it possible to (easily) get notified of conversation LIFETIME timeout event, so I can handle removing the dialog record from the table by myself?

Thanks for sharing.

Jean-Yves

Comment: I don't understand your concern.  If you are reusing a pool of dialog conversations, what are you thinking would "grow unexpectedly"?

Answer (score 0):

I use that same technique and I'm not worried about the roughly 70 years (!!) that would need to elapse before the max value for a (signed) int would expire. I'll for sure be dead by the time that happens and likely the database will be as well.

That said, I have thought about setting lifetimes recently. How I'd do it is set up an Agent job to detect that some conversations are about to expire and soon up new ones to replace them. One those new handles are verified as working, call `END CONVERSATION` on the old ones.